# Sky Train Blimp Plane?

Tags: physics, environment, flight, electricity, power-sources

Can using blimps to hold power lines and implement laser filamentation of ablout 7 meter span from the source of power for a contact free power supply to power an electric engine (designed to run on super high voltage low amperage) plane or blimp be done in this way?

[image]

Battery weight prevents an efficient means of travel and we are far from creating a battery light enough to be efficient. The plane does the lifting not the rail. In the event of a plane stall the whole rail would slowly descend safely.

[image]

[image]

I could not find pictures were anyone had done this with weather balloons. Could enough whether balloons be chained to even climb it?

Electricity arcing along a straight path of ions created by the high temperature laser on top picture transfers the most efficient way to transfer large amount of electricity or power without a wire currently. The air acts as a natural insulator can be projected accurately miles long if needed. The planes laser would shoot the rail many times a second and electricity would travel back to the plane with almost no loss of efficiency in transmission.

Related:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16980/what-are-the-hurdles-to-overcome-before-purely-electric-commercial-aircraft-can

[What would make Electric Airlines possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29411/what-would-make-electric-airlines-possible?rq=1)

Comment: Even if this is possible, why not just do a hyperloop (tunnel with evacuated air) or monorail (rail close to the ground)?  Why is it important to get the rail as far off the ground as a plane?

Comment: Are you sure a laser ionizing miles or air, and a lightning rod are lighter than batteries? If you are tethered a few miles from infrastructure what is the point of a drone not needing to refuel?

Comment: It would seem much simpler, and much more efficient, just to use the electricity to synthesize a hydrocarbon fuel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Liek Myrabo](https://infogalactic.com/info/Leik_Myrabo) has taken that idea to 11 by bypassing electrification and harnessing the power of lasers to directly power aerodynes and spacecraft, something he calls a "[Lightcraft](https://infogalactic.com/info/Lightcraft)".

[image]

*Basic concept. The mirror on the bottom focuses the laser so intently the air explodes into a plasma for thrust*

[image]

*Model of the lightcraft*

[image]

*Model Lightcraft under laser power*

While sadly the funding for this research has not been forthcoming, there have been [proof of principle flights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_9ac-w4DW8) and [open air flights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAdj6vpYppA), so this does work. (more about this [here](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/414629/riding-an-energy-beam-to-space/))

Now strictly speaking this is a ramjet or thermal rocket (depending on if you are using air as the reaction mass or an on board propellant like water or liquid hydrogen), but since the laser itself is likely to be electrically powered, then you *could* make the case this is an electric aircraft.

Comment: Myrabo has done calculations for laser powered spacecraft up to the size of the Space Shuttle, so in theory there is no limit beyond how much laser energy you can send. The best way to use this technology is to blast into a ballistic path and coast, using a laser at the receiving end to provide thrust to brake and land.

Comment: I thought the concept was clear enough, laser energy from an off board laser shines on the focusing mirror and the focused laser energy turns air (or injected reaction mass) into plasma for thrust. You will be traveling at hypersonic speeds fairly quickly (since this was designed to launch ships into orbit). A ground laser shines on the craft, it lifts off and accelerates to speed, coasts in a ballistic arc to the destination and a second laser shines on the craft to land for suborbital flight. London to Sydney Australia in 2hrs.

Comment: Of course there would be attenuation of a laser in atmosphere, but the loss of electrical conductivity over distance is, as a rule, worse than directed EM radiation.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/103487/can-nuclear-material-be-used-to-propel-this-way I based this question off your answer what do you think? please please edit if you can.

Answer (score 6):

This is potentially more a [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) question than a worldbuilding one, but my (relative) layman's viewpoint:

Lightning (artificial or natural) is *really* hard to harness efficiently.  In order to get an arc you need extremely high voltage, which, generally, means ultra-low amperage to go with it, unless you have an excessive amount of power.  This means that you'd need ultra-heavy-duty circuits to handle the power, supercapacitors to be able to store the power in such a short window, etc.

This would also be extraordinarily dangerous, since, even with laser-induced ionization, you could run into the "rails" grounding out if a better path (say, natural lightning's positive trailers?) offered itself - which is far more likely in the air than with conventional electrified rails.

I'm also skeptical of "almost no loss of electricity".  The energy expended by the ionizing laser is almost certainly lost in its entirety, and since what you're creating is effectively artificial lightning, you're losing energy to light and heat generated by its transmission as well.

Of potentially greater merit - if you've got a laser powerful enough to ionize the air to allow the electricity to arc to your receiver on the aircraft, why not skip the middleman and have photovoltaics on the aircraft to receive beamed power from the ground?  It has to be more efficient, and this is actually a thing [that has been demonstrated](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/armstrong/news/FactSheets/FS-087-DFRC.html).

Comment: You can think what you want; wireless delivery of electricity in bulk is no more efficient than collimated light delivery.  Also, the longest distance over which laser filaments can deliver electricity is in the range of single-digit metres - not really practical for the speed and range of heavier-than-air flight.

Comment: A laser isn't a "really focused flashlight".  The proof of concept was a focused flashlight, but was also inside a building and focused on a UAV.  Tends to be cheaper that way.  A practical beamed-power system would presumably use laser light to reduce both spread and attenuation.

Comment: Additional supporting information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power_transfer#Far-field_(radiative)_techniques

Answer (score 1):

One big problem that I see from the three images of the balloon chain is that the chain is not straight.  In the image with the pink balloons, if you could follow that path with any vehicle I doubt that it would be comfortable at over 60 mph.  So if the plane is to go 500 mph, then the wire needs to be very straight which means very stiff and thus very heavy.  By very heavy, I mean to the point where it isn't cost effective to hold them up with balloons.

Comment: That requires a fine day from point A to point B, so the plane service would be at the mercy of the weather.   As the speed of the plane increases the turbulence from the plane affects the balloon.